# SQL primary key default value with char

Tags: sql

I need to distinct my primary key with Employee and User so i want my primary key for employee to have 'E' before the num. is that even possible?

Comment: sounds like a bad idea.  It would be more appropriate to have a Role column which has E or U in it to specify the role (or an associative entity if they can be both).  The purpose of a PK in a DB is not to add meaning or context to the row.

Answer (score 1):

Doing that is a bad idea, not only because it adds meaning to a primary key which shouldn't be there (what if you decide to hire one of your users?), but also because it would require you to change an int field to a char/varchar, slowing down queries.

To accomplish what (I think) you want, you could make another field called PersonType and then you could "Select * from Employee where PersonType = 'E'  " or the like.  You could even put an index on PersonType to make queries against it faster.

Is there different data that you'd like to store for employees vs users?  For example, do you want to store the home address of your employees but not your users, or the credit card number of your users but not your employees?  In this case, you'd want another *table* to hold the additional information, not just another column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display something like that, I would use an autogenerated number as my PK. Then I would have a column with person_type and then I might have a persisted calculated column that combined the two.

Note I would only do this is the person could **NEVER** be in both categories. If there is a possiblity that someone could  be in both categories, I would have a related table for the person_type and add the persisted calculated column to this table.